# How to plot a spherical segment in Python?

Tags: python, mplot3d

How can one plot a spherical segment, specifically a sphere "slice" in Python?

I know how to plot a sphere surface via

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = 10 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 10 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 10 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='b')
plt.show()
```

or some variation of that code, but I'm struggeling to plot only a part of the sphere, leading to an image like the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment#/media/File:LaoHaiKugelschicht1.png

If I vary the code I presented above by manipulating the definitions of u and v, e.g.:

```
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 20)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 20)
```

the sphere is still presented as a whole, but with a very poor resolution.
Changing the starting point of the linspace range doens't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out something that works for me. Here you go:

```
q = 0.5  # defines upper starting point of the spherical segment
p = 0.8  # defines ending point of the spherical segment as ratio


u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(q, p * np.pi, p * 100)
x = r * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v)) + x_0
y = r * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v)) + y_0
z = r * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v)) + z_0
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='b')
```

[image]